# Recursive deletion with apply template

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to transform the following XML file, to remove each `<AGGREGATION>` node if followed by a `<MULTIPLE>` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" TRACK="1">
        <FIELD NAME="PRODUCT" BASE="CT300" COUNT="2">
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="4" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <TOKEN TEXT="CT300" BEGIN="11379" END="11384"/>
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="9" />
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="4" />
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="4" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES" />
            <TOKEN TEXT="CT300" BEGIN="11379" END="11384"/>
        </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
```

With the following xslt transformation, I was able to remove only the first occurrence of the `<AGGREGATION>` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                        
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="//RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/AGGREGATION[following-sibling::*[1][self::MULTIPLE]]">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/AGGREGATION[following-sibling::*[1][self::MULTIPLE]]">
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" TRACK="1">
        <FIELD BASE="CT300" COUNT="2" NAME="PRODUCT">
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="11379" END="11384" TEXT="CT300"/>
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="9"/>
            <AGGREGATION DOMAIN="4"/>

            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="11379" END="11384" TEXT="CT300"/>
        </FIELD>
   </RECORD>
```

While the desired output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RECORD TEMPLATE="PRODUCTS" TRACK="1">
        <FIELD BASE="CT300" COUNT="2" NAME="PRODUCT">

            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="11379" END="11384" TEXT="CT300"/>             
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <MULTIPLE TYPE="YES"/>
            <TOKEN BEGIN="11379" END="11384" TEXT="CT300"/>
        </FIELD>
 </RECORD>
```

How can I implement a recursive deletion of the `<AGGREGATION>` node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

1. Write a template matching `AGGREGATION`.
2. The decision whether it shoud copy anything is as follows:

   - Take the first following sibling with name != `AGGREGATION`.
   - Check whether its name is `MULTIPLE`.
   - If yes, do nothing (skip the current `AGGREGATION` element).
   - If not, apply templates for the current element.
3. You need also the *identity template*.

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="AGGREGATION">
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[name()!='AGGREGATION'][1]
      [name()='MULTIPLE'])">
      <AGGREGATION>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </AGGREGATION>
    </xsl:if>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/bEJaofQ/1

Comment: The output in your working example does not match what was requested. Also, the OP's solution did not fail because the XPath started with `//`. It's not necessary, but it doesn't hurt anything. In fact, just by adding an additional predicate to the XPaths, the OP's stylesheet works: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8o

Comment: *Daniel*, you are right. My first solution removed only the last `AGGREGATION` element it the series. Now I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this empty template plus the *identity template* to eradicate the unwanted `<AGGREGATION>` elements conditionally:

```
<xsl:template match="AGGREGATION[following-sibling::*[1] = (self::MULTIPLE or self::AGGREGATION)]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to ignore the following sibling `AGGREGATION` elements...

```
<xsl:template match="RECORD[@TEMPLATE='PRODUCTS']/FIELD[@NAME='PRODUCT']/AGGREGATION[following-sibling::*[not(self::AGGREGATION)][1][self::MULTIPLE]]"/>
```